# Rounding to even single decimal point in Java

Tags: java

I am looking for the best way to round to **even** decimal values. For example I have a double = 4.267833399 and I want to round to the nearest even single decimal place, in this case 4.2 and not 4.3. And 4.3165656 would round to 4.4 not 4.3. 
I have searched hard and havent found a simple way to do this.

I would like the result as a double.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: A quick google search would lead you to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-

Comment: Are you looking for the result (4.2) as a `double` or as a `String`?

Comment: or as a BigDecimal?

Comment: Isnt 4.3 the nearest number to one decimal place?

Comment: @shmosel - it isn't clear: I read the question as doing a `double` to `double` rounding, not `double` to `String` conversion.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I think the key part is "... to _even_ single decimal point".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want your answer in a `double`, this should work:

```
double result = Math.round(input * 5) / 5d;
```

Comment: Probably best to avoid using a `float`, just divide by `5.0`

Comment: Not to be confused with `0x5d` ;)

Comment: This is perfect thanks. Now if only I could understand the maths of it.

Comment: It's easier to understand the rounding to a single decimal point case - basically you do `Math.round(v * 10) / 10d`. That first shifts the decimal place one point to the left, then rounds it off, and then shifts it back to the left. So you can use `Math.round()` by shifting the point around to where you want it, then shifting it back. The even case with a multiplier of 5 works similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You can round to one decimal place with

```
double d = Math.round(x * 10) / 10.0;
```

Note this will round 4.26 up to 4.3 as it is the closest, if you want to always round down you can do

```
double d = (long) (x * 10) / 10.0;
```

> I want to round to the nearest even single decimal place

If you want to round to the nearest multiple of 0.2 you can do

```
double d = Math.round(x * 5) / 5.0;
```

This will round `4.299` to `4.2` and `4.3` to `4.4`

Comment: Yes I do indeed want to round to the nearest "even" decimal point. I.e 4.2, 4.4, 4.6 etc.

Comment: @DBell in that case, using round is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
double myNumber = 12345.6789;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
df.format(myNumber);
```

This would return `12345.7`

Edit: Noticed you're looking for rounding to an even number. You could use the above method of rounding and then conditionally manipulate your number after if the decimal is odd.